# Angular: update scope with async AJAX data from a factory

Tags: ajax, angularjs

What's the recommended way to do this?

1.

```
factory.updater = function(varObjToBeUpdated){
    $http.post('/url', {})
    .success(function(data){
        for (data_field in data)
            varObjToBeUpdated[data_field] = data[data_field];
    });
} 

...

myFactory.updater($scope.varObjToBeUpdated);
```

Or 2.,

```
 myFactory.updater().success(function(data, ..){
    $scope.varObjToBeUpdated = data;
});

...

factory.updater = function(){
    return $http.post('/url', {});
}
```

---

Is it ok to to pass a reference scope variable to a factory? I always thought factories as *delivering* data.

And what's wrong with the second method (if it's less acceptable)?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Sorry, I think the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the second approach, as this allows you to just inject the service when you need it across multiple controllers. Use `.then` to continue the promise pattern:

```
myFactory.updater().then(function(data, ..){
    $scope.varObjToBeUpdated = data;
});

app.factory('myFactor', function($http) {
    return {
        updater: function() {
            return $http({'/url',}).then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```